# npm install lame error windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, lame

this is my error when running `npm install lame`:

```
C:\Users\zmoze\Documents\Vault\Code\ZachsBot>npm install lame
npm WARN package.json ZachsBot@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ZachsBot@0.0.1 No README data

> lame@1.2.4 install         
C:\Users\zmoze\Documents\Vault\Code\ZachsBot\node_modules\lame
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\zmoze\Documents\Vault\Code\ZachsBot\node_modules\lame>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Users\zmoze\Documents\Vault\Code\ZachsBot\node_modules\lame\build\deps\mpg123\..\..\..\deps\mpg123\test_output.c
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.InvalidToolsetDefinitionException: MSBuildToolsPath is not specified for the ToolsVersion "14.0" defined at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0", or the value specified evaluates to the empty string.
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.InvalidToolsetDefinitionException.Throw(Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ToolsetReader.ReadToolset(PropertyDefinition toolsVersion, BuildPropertyGroup globalProperties, BuildPropertyGroup initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ToolsetReader.ReadEachToolset(ToolsetCollection toolsets, BuildPropertyGroup globalProperties, BuildPropertyGroup initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ToolsetReader.ReadToolsets(ToolsetCollection toolsets, BuildPropertyGroup globalProperties, BuildPropertyGroup initialProperties, Boolean accumulateProperties)
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ToolsetReader.ReadAllToolsets(ToolsetCollection toolsets, ToolsetRegistryReader registryReader, ToolsetConfigurationReader configurationReader, BuildPropertyGroup globalProperties, BuildPropertyGroup initialProperties, ToolsetDefinitionLocations locations)
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.PopulateToolsetStateMap(ToolsetDefinitionLocations locations)
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine..ctor(Int32 numberOfCpus, Boolean isChildNode, Int32 parentNodeId, String localNodeProviderParameters, BuildPropertyGroup globalProperties, ToolsetDefinitionLocations locations)
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.get_GlobalEngine()
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project..ctor(Engine engine, String toolsVersion)
at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.SolutionWrapperProject.Generate(String solutionPath, String toolsVersionOverride, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.GenerateSolutionWrapperUsingOldOM(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.LoadSolutionForBuild(String projectFile, PropertyDictionary`1 globalPropertiesInstances, String toolsVersion, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.LoadSolutionIntoConfiguration(BuildRequestConfiguration config, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.IssueRequestToScheduler(BuildSubmission submission, Boolean allowMainThreadBuild, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass60_1.<ExecuteSubmission>b__0()

MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.InvalidToolsetDefinitionException: MSBuildToolsPath is not specified for the ToolsVersion "14.0" defined at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0", or the value specified evaluates to the empty string.
at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.BuildProject(String projectFile, String[] targets, String toolsVersion, Dictionary`2 globalProperties, ILogger[] loggers, LoggerVerbosity verbosity, DistributedLoggerRecord[] distributedLoggerRecords, Boolean needToValidateProject, String schemaFile, Int32 cpuCount, Boolean enableNodeReuse, TextWriter preprocessWriter, Boolean debugger, Boolean detailedSummary)
at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String commandLine)

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.InvalidToolsetDefinitionException: MSBuildToolsPath is not specified for the ToolsVersion "14.0" defined at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0", or the value specified evaluates to the empty string.
at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.BuildProject(String projectFile, String[] targets, String toolsVersion, Dictionary`2 globalProperties, ILogger[] loggers, LoggerVerbosity verbosity, DistributedLoggerRecord[] distributedLoggerRecords, Boolean needToValidateProject, String schemaFile, Int32 cpuCount, Boolean enableNodeReuse, TextWriter preprocessWriter, Boolean debugger, Boolean detailedSummary)
at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String commandLine)
at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Main()
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit 
code: 3762504530
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\zmoze\Documents\Vault\Code\ZachsBot\node_modules\lame
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "lame"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! lame@1.2.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lame@1.2.4 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the lame package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs lame
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls lame
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zmoze\Documents\Vault\Code\ZachsBot\npm-debug.log
```

I have already installed `node-lame` in the location where I am.

Comment: what version of visual studio do you have installed?

Comment: Are you sure it is supported?  According to [docs on node-lame on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lame) "Linux or Mac OS (Windows is NOT tested by this package)".

Comment: do you have a c++ compiler installed ?   node needs one to enable npm to compile  source packages

Comment: the node module is just a wrapper ... first install lame  http://lame.sourceforge.net/  ... assure you have a c++ compiler

Comment: I downloaded the tar.gz... what do I do with it? @ScottStensland